# Failed when launching thrift server for Hbase in Docker

Tags: hbase, thrift, boot2docker

I am trying to launch thrift Server for HBase(for .NET Client), using this command below :

```
docker exec -it hbase /opt/hbase/bin/hbase thrift start&
```

it never gets started. Just stops when I try to check processes running using docker ps. how do I verify exactly whats causing the issue  to start thrift server and the port on which its running ?